# Matlab to python logic difficulty for arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I have created an m-by-n matrix in MATLAB and can easily select a range of values within a certain column and row. For instance, if I have matrix `A`:

```
A =

 0     0     0     0
 1     2     3     4
 5     6     7     8
 9    10    11    12
```

I can isolate the values: 1,5 and 9 from the first column by typing: `A(2:4,1)`. The results will yield `[1;5;9]`. As it relates to python, I am not sure how to index an array such that I have the desired values as above.

Comment: Is this a numpy array? If so, it's just as easy as in Matlab. If not, have you considered using a numpy array instead? `np.asarray(x)`. Check out [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think that would work, but it does. I guess I was confused by the different indexing techniques python uses. For example, if I wanted to isolate 9 from the matrix A, I would type A(4,1), but in python I could either type A[3,0] or A[3][0]. I guess I'm more confused with which technique to use in what instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using numpy

`a = numpy.matrix('0 0 0 0; 1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12')`

Required result is `a[1:,0]` or `a[1:4,0]`

Only difference is that the array indexing start from 0 instead of 1.

Comment: You should be using numpy arrays rather than numpy matrices.  The Python community has standardized around arrays so they are much more broadly-support, and they work better for pretty much all use-cases especially now that they have a matrix multiplication operator.